# Working with django channels and websockets

Tags: python, django, websocket, django-rest-framework, django-channels

I have a form to input Line coordinates at *127.0.0.1:8000/dashboard/* and an "Ok" button to submit the coordinates. The coordinates are posted at *127.0.0.1:8000/api/line/* by calling the view `LineDisplay()`. Here I want to push the Line coordinates back to *127.0.01:8000/dashboard/*.

I have done the following so far:

urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url,include
from django.contrib import admin
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^api/line/$',views.LineDisplay.as_view()),
]
```

view.py:

```
class LineDisplay(APIView):
"""
Display the most recent line
"""

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        lines = Line.objects.all()
        serializer = LineSerializer(lines, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        lines = Line.objects.all()
        for line in lines:
            line.delete();
        serializer = LineSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
        info = ""
        info += "Line Coordinates are: "
        lines = Line.objects.all()
        for line in lines:
            info += "x1:" + str(line.x1)
            info += " y1:" + str(line.y1)
            info += " x2:" + str(line.x2)
            info += " y2:" + str(line.y2)
        print info
        Channel('repeat-me').send({'info': info, 'status': True})
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

consumers.py

```
import json

# In consumers.py
from channels import Group

# Connected to websocket.connect
def ws_add(message):
    Group("chat").add(message.reply_channel)

# Connected to websocket.receive
def ws_message(message):
     print "Receive Message now"
     Group("chat").send({
        "text": json.dumps({'status': False})
    })
# Connected to websocket.disconnect
def ws_disconnect(message):
    Group("chat").discard(message.reply_channel)


def repeat_me(message):
    Group("chat").send({
    "text": json.dumps({'status': message.content['status'], 'info':      
     message.content['info']})
     })
```

Similarly, I have added added the following code to : routing.py

```
from channels.routing import route
from .consumers import ws_add, ws_message, ws_disconnect, repeat_me

channel_routing = [
    route("websocket.connect", ws_add),
    route("websocket.receive", ws_message),
    route("websocket.disconnect", ws_disconnect),
    route("repeat-me", repeat_me),
]
```

The following lines have been added to settings.py:

```
CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    "default": {
        "BACKEND": "asgiref.inmemory.ChannelLayer",
        "ROUTING": "TrainingInduct.routing.channel_routing",
    },
}
```

Currently, I don't know how to deal with the group "chat". I don't even need a group. What are the remaining things to be done in order to get the line coordinates to be displayed at *127.0.0.1:8000/dashboard/* as soon as a new line is posted?

Note: The Line coordinates are getting properly POSTED to */api/line/* I think I might have to write a server code in order to get the data from the channel and push it back, am I right? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need the group to collect all the Channels that should receive your info. Each connected device gets one Channel.

A device's channel identifier is in the `message.reply_channel`. A Group is just a way to collect all the `message.reply_channel`s.

So, let's say any user who opens your `/dashboard/` page will receive any new "info" item that is posted. First, you need to remember the new client's Channel. That's what your `ws_add` is for

```
def ws_add(message):
    Group("all-my-clients").add(message.reply_channel)
```

Now the client who just connected is part of the `all-my-clients` Group, and whatever message you send via `all-my-clients`, will be send automatically to that client as well.

Of course you want to clean up after yourself, so that's what `ws_disconnect` is for. Remove the client once they do a WebSocket.close() or they close their browser, etc.

```
def ws_disconnect(message):
    Group("all-my-clients").discard(message.reply_channel)
```

And finally, there is your `ws_message()`. It receives any incoming messages.

```
def ws_message(message):
    # Nothing to do here, because you only push, never receive.
    pass
```

That's all. Now you can just send messages to the Group you defined above from anywhere in Django. Just make sure you send the response in the correct format. `Group().send()` takes a `dict` with a key `text` that has a string value (see below). The reason is that you could also send other data types, like blobs. But "text" is best for this purpose.

```
def post(self, request, format=None):
    lines = Line.objects.all()
    ...
    print info
    response_data = {'info': info, 'status': True}
    Group("all-my-clients").send({
        'text': json.dumps(response_data)
    })
    return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

That should be all.